# How can I call OpenCV focalsFromHomography from Python?

Tags: python, opencv

[OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dbc/group__stitching__autocalib.html) says

```
focalsFromHomography()
void cv::detail::focalsFromHomography   (const Mat &H,
    double &    f0,
    double &    f1,
    bool &      f0_ok,
    bool &      f1_ok 
)       
Python:
    cv.detail.focalsFromHomography( H, f0, f1, f0_ok, f1_ok ) -> None
```

and indeed I can call focalsFromHomography this way, without error:

```
    f0 = 0.0
    f1 = 0.0
    f0_ok = False
    f1_ok = False
    r = cv.detail.focalsFromHomography(
        mat,
        f0, f1,
        f0_ok, f1_ok
    )
```

Of course, it does not return anything, and it does not, cannot, change f0 and f1.

If I call it like this:

```
    f0 = c_double()
    f1 = c_double()
    f0_ok = c_bool()
    f1_ok = c_bool()
    r = cv.detail.focalsFromHomography(
        mat,
        byref(f0), byref(f1),
        byref(f0_ok), byref(f1_ok)
    )
```

I get an error "TypeError: Argument 'f0' can not be treated as a double", which is true, f0 is not a double, but a reference to a double, because I want to receive the result in f0.

How can I call "focalsFromHomography" and receive the estimated focals?

So far my only solution is to copy the algorithm from [OpenCV source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/stitching/src/autocalib.cpp) and manually translate it to Python code, line by line. It is only 20 lines, so it is doable, but it is not nice.

Comment: You can't, and due to how the Python API is implemented, using ctypes like you tried won't help. File a bug on OpenCV's github -- this will need a hand-written wrapper to deal with the references. Until that's done, translating the implementation to Python is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I am answering my own question. It looks like that rewriting the code in Python seems to be the only solution.

```
@staticmethod
def _focalsfromhomography(
    mat: np.ndarray) -> tuple[float | None, float | None]:
    """
    Estimate focal lengths from the given homography under
    the assumption that the camera undergoes rotations
    around its center only.

    https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dbc/group__stitching__autocalib.html
    https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/stitching/src/autocalib.cpp
    Rewriten in pure Python, because it was a bit difficult
    to call the native OpenCV function.
    :param mat: Homography matrix
    :return: (f0, f1)
    """
    # Fast access
    h = np.reshape(mat, 9)

    # f1
    f1 = None
    # Denominators
    d1 = h[6] * h[7]
    d2 = (h[7] - h[6]) * (h[7] + h[6])
    # Focal squares value candidates
    v1 = -(h[0] * h[1] + h[3] * h[4])
    v1 = v1 / d1 if d1 != 0.0 else -1.0
    v2 = (h[0] - h[1]) * (h[0] + h[1]) + (h[3] - h[4]) * (h[3] + h[4])
    v2 = v2 / d2 if d2 != 0.0 else -1.0
    if v1 < v2:
        v1, v2 = v2, v1
    if v1 > 0 and v2 > 0:
        f1 = math.sqrt(v1 if abs(d1) > abs(d2) else v2)
    elif v1 > 0:
        f1 = math.sqrt(v1)

    # f0
    f0 = None
    # Denominators
    d1 = h[0] * h[3] + h[1] * h[4]
    d2 = (h[0] - h[3]) * (h[0] + h[3]) + (h[1] - h[4]) * (h[1] + h[4])
    # Focal squares value candidates
    v1 = -h[2] * h[5]
    v1 = v1 / d1 if d1 != 0.0 else -1.0
    v2 = (h[5] - h[2]) * (h[5] + h[2])
    v2 = v2 / d2 if d2 != 0.0 else -1.0
    if v1 < v2:
        v1, v2 = v2, v1
    if v1 > 0 and v2 > 0:
        f0 = math.sqrt(v1 if abs(d1) > abs(d2) else v2)
    elif v1 > 0:
        f0 = math.sqrt(v1)

    return f0, f1
```

This works, but it isn't the solution I am looking for. I hope someone can do it better.